# how to change style prev-icon & next-icon props in vuetify <v-slide-group>?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am trying add background color and change the icon color on prev icon and next icon on vuetify slide group prop. if i target the  class which i got from console it's not working. but if i remove scoped from my style tag or try to change the color on console style it's working.

```
 .v-slide-group__next.theme--light.v-icon
{
    color: rgb(234, 10, 10)!important;

}
```

I have tried this way but it's not working.how can i style those props icon? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to target the elements with class it's necessary to use `<style>` without 'scopped', because 'scopped' automatically adds unique hashes in the class selector on each app build. And this prevents targeting Vuetify's elements using this way. I would suggest you to add some class on your wrapper container, let's say class="my-slider" and to target it like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <v-slide-group class="my-slider">
 </div>
</template>
<style>
.my-slider > .v-slide-group__next.theme--light.v-icon
{
    color: rgb(234, 10, 10)!important;

}
</style>
```